# Lombok: publicly immutable (over setters) object with all and no arguments constructor, hash, equals and toString

Tags: jpa, constructor, entity, immutability, lombok

We use Lombok for our entities to generate that common boilerplate, like constructors, hash/equals and toString.

In the same time we'd like to keep our objects immutable. Unfortunately, we can't make the completely immutable (e.g. with `final` properties) because JPA/Hibernate processors required no-args constructor and sets properties over reflection.

- `@lombok.Data` doesn't fit because it creates public setters
- `@lombok.Value` doesn't fit because it makes properties `final` and Hibernate can't set them over reflection.

what really fits us is:

```
@Getter 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@EqualsAndHashCode 
@ToString
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

But this again creates a boilerplate for us, copy-pasting 5 annotations every time and messing the code.

Unfortunately i have not found any way in Lombok to aggregate annotations to some meta-annotation, like in Spring.

Question: **is there any out-of-box annotation in Lombok to generate such *publicly immutable entities*?**

Or

**is there any way to declare local meta-annotation**?

Comment: See e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/project-lombok/CnvM6MbRSw8

Comment: ok, this means no way so far to aggregate annotations ((

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a slightly lighter version:

```
@Data
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

with the following in `lombok.config` file:

```
lombok.noArgsConstructor.extraPrivate = true
```

I'm not sure whether the `extraPrivate` configuration works in Lombok 1.18.0. It should, according to the [changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog), but I was unable to make it work in a quick attempt.

Comment: but then extra private constructor applies to all entities in the package. And having `lombok.config` file instead of annotation doesn't make easier to read and understand the entities.

Comment: @radistao No-arg constructor will apply to all entities that use `@Data` or `@Value` annotation, yes. It shouldn't be a problem, though, as it is _private_. I also don't see why having this set in `lombok.config` should make it problematic to understand entities since the private constructor is just an implementation detail, and not the API of the entity. However, I understand that this solution is far from perfect, as you still have two annotations (including ugly `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)`) instead of one. Obviously, aggregate annotations (if they were available) would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You may still use `@Data` annotations, but provide private setters

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private int id;
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: thank it creates another boilerplate: put access level on every property.

Comment: Yeah, definitely agreed. You may however use some kind of DTO objects, which are immutable and work with them. In that case you would use your `@Entity` object just to communicate with the DB. What about `lombok`, I`m not sure if you can do what you mentioned before